# Transform multi-dimensional JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have the following javascript (typescript) array:

```
[[1262304000000,0.7537], [1262563200000,0.6951], [1262649600000,0.6925]]
```

How can I transform it to the following using map operator?  (Basically second element of the array has been converted to % value. E.g. 0.7537 to 75.37. However, I am not sure how to access the second element of the array)

```
[[1262304000000,75.37], [1262563200000,69.51], [1262649600000,69.25]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of your array is itself an array, and therefore you can [access its elements via numeric indices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#array_indices) like `v[0]` for the first element and `v[1]` for the second:

```
const a = [[1262304000000,0.7537], [1262563200000,0.6951], [1262649600000,0.6925]];
console.log(a.map(v => [v[0], v[1] * 100]));
// [[1262304000000, 75.37], [1262563200000, 69.51], [1262649600000, 69.25]]
```

But it's also easy to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to copy each element's members into individual named parameters before using them:

```
const a = [[1262304000000,0.7537], [1262563200000,0.6951], [1262649600000,0.6925]];
console.log(a.map(([x, y]) => [x, y*100]));
// [[1262304000000, 75.37], [1262563200000, 69.51], [1262649600000, 69.25]]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA1JBvAUEnT4HtgoAXJEJAXiQG1qBGAJgDYGBmABgBZ2feAaJOwB0AdgCsrEQF0B9ZgzFNWDXjwHCmATjF0ZNRiyadNTVe3VCtCqVIDc2XASL4ANhCEv8AcwAUIIWAgMD4AbpQAfDQh1Ox60bpIAFRIdDxSAJTp9rhIAPS5NHIsHNxmAuJCknpFCkoqqgJaQjrVBszGpg1ITdZSSJgAvphOJGSUhW0lZuaCohLSsm2KymWzWi2L8kYmqxqavfYjru6evv6BwT7UAB4CAJ4ZETS3SHdJKWmZ9kA)

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = [[1262304000000, 0.7537], [1262563200000, 0.6951], [1262649600000, 0.6925]];

const convertedData = data.map(item => {
  const timestamp = item[0];
  const percent = item[1] * 100; // Convert the second item to a percentage
  return [timestamp, percent]; // return both items
});

console.log(convertedData);
```